# Google play console, internal test still appears(to me!)

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I know this question has been around but i just can´t find the solution for this, so i was hopping someone could give me some tips on how to resolve this.

I was using for the first time the internal tests, so i went and upload a version of the app, but the thing is, i made a mistake...i though i had the version 1.3 and so i was going to test the version 1.4, but it turns out, i had the version 1.2 in the store and i should have uploaded a version 1.3. Now the following is happening:

1. The apk is in the artifacts library(and i can´t delete it)
2. When i click to "remove testers"(which is just me!) in the manage internal tests it saves, but then, when i want to exit the page it says there are unsaved alterations, what?!?
3. This is the most annoying part, if i go to google play(on my pc), i can see the new version i uploaded the 1.3(for production), but if i go to my phone, i still see the version 1.4 and if i download it, it´s not the same as the new 1.3.

Has anyone experience this? please help because i don´t know what to do.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You post is a bit confusing since you're mixing internal test and production it seems. Assuming your versionCode scheme follows your version names, Play will not update version 1.3 over version 1.4, because 1.4 > 1.3. This is a security feature of the Android platform: you can only install APKs that have a higher versionCode than the already installed APK.

Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for answering, yes i know, the post is confusing, i´m sorry. Let´s just say that in the store right know there is a production version 1.3(which is correct) and in the internal tests, there is a version 1.4(which is wrong, i made a mistake in the version numbers), and now, im my own android phone i can only see version 1.4 in the google play store, but it´s just me, i know that for others, the version 1.3 is appearing. I already removed myself from testers but then the other issue appears. :(

Comment: "You would need to uninstall the installed APK before switching between the two" and how do i do that? i already unistall the app, i already cleared cache and removed myself from beta testers etc, how can i acomplish that? show i create a 1.5 version and this would be resolved? would this 1.5 version go over the 1.4 even if the 1.4 it´s only in internal test?

Comment: Sorry, I confused internal testing track and internal app sharing, I edited my answer. There may be some propagation delay when you opt out from beta testing, after which you should receive 1.3 again. Publishing 1.5 would definitely solve the problem but seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pierre.